# Ошибка уровня защиты класса

Tags: c#

Код класса

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KusokBIB
{
    class TablicaNikosik
    {
        public double a, b, h, max, x, y;


        public static double VvodList(TextBox t)
        {
            return Convert.ToDouble(t.Text);
        }

        public static void VivodList(TextBox t, double z)
        {

           t.Text = Convert.ToString(z);

        }

        public static double CiklEasy(double a,double  b, double  h)
        {
            double  max, y, x;

            max = -30000;

            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((b - a) / h) + 1);

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                x = a + (i - 1) * h;
                y = Math.Pow(2, -x) * Math.Exp(x);

                if (y > max)
                    max = y;


            }
            return max;
        }

    }
}
```

Код формы

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using KusokBIB;

namespace Лабораторные_работы
{
    public partial class Form11 : Form
    {
        public Form11()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TablicaNikosik tablicaNikosik = new TablicaNikosik();
            tablicaNikosik.a = TablicaNikosik.VvodList(textBox1);
            tablicaNikosik.b = TablicaNikosik.VvodList(textBox2);
            tablicaNikosik.h = TablicaNikosik.VvodList(textBox3);
            tablicaNikosik.max = TablicaNikosik.CiklEasy(tablicaNikosik.a, tablicaNikosik.b, tablicaNikosik.h);
        }
    }
}
```

В форме кода выводится ошибка о том что TablicaNikosik не доступен из за уровня защиты. Не понимаю в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class TablicaNikosik
^^^^^^
```